# How do I deserialize a deconstructed List?

Tags: java, deserialization

I have a TreeMap I'm trying to make serializable, but instead of sending the entire object, I want to deconstruct it, send the data, and reconstruct at the other end.
I serialize it with

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, LinkedList<T>> entry: map.entrySet()) {
    s.writeObject("p"+entry.getKey());

    for (T t : entry.getValue()) {
        s.writeObject(t);
    }
}
```

I will deserialize it with something like

```
LinkedList<T> list = new LinkedList<>();
int p = Integer.parseInt(((String) s.readObject()).substring(1));

while (s.available() != 0) {
    Object o = s.readObject();
    
    if (((String) o).charAt(0) == 'p') {
        store.put(p, new LinkedList<>(list));
        p = Integer.parseInt(((String) o).substring(1));
        list = new LinkedList<>();

    } else {
        list.add((T) o);
    }
}
```

The question I have is whether there is a better way to know when the object has finished sending than `available` being 0?

(Answers such as "Why are you doing it that way, just use default serialization" are not helpful.)

Comment: Then let's comment: why are you doing this? (it is okay for educational purposes, to learn how to do it manually, but a complete waste of time otherwise)

Comment: And then: why not provide a [mcve]? Instead of fragments of code that lack context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serialization format you're using doesn't have enough information to reconstruct the list -- e.g. if a `T` is a `String` starting with `p`.

Instead, first, serialize the number of entries in the map as an `int`.  Then, that many times, serialize the key, and then `entry.getValue().size()`, and then the values.

That provides enough information at the other end to deserialize precisely the right amount.